# Is there a C++ implementation of Node.js Net API?

Tags: c++, node.js

Node.js has a very good and well thought Net API. 
I wonder is there a good C++ ***only*** implementation of that API as for example LuaNode do for Lua?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [node.native](https://github.com/d5/node.native) - attempt to implement api similar to node.js core lib, but with c++11 (and evented IO is also based on libuv)

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing very similar that I know of.

However there are several reactor frameworks out there which give the same event queue driven environment. For example [boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) provides an event queue that makes callbacks to handle network events, timers, and arbiatary events that you push onto the event queue.

It's largely the same idea, used in the same way. Howver it's nowhere near as simple as node.js to get started with, and does provide any non-blocking functions other than the basics I said above.

It does provide you with the environment to build your own system though. It's an excellent library, but probably rather lower level than you are looking for. There are other simiar libraries such as ACE and parts of the POCO c++ libraries too, but again, they are lower level than node.js with much less library support.

edit:
I've not looked at it too much but how about this https://github.com/joyent/libuv . This is a library that is used to implement some of the node.js features in a cross platform way. Maybe it's possible to use some of it for what you need?

Comment: Actually I'm struggling right now with the boost::asio and it is indeed much more low level then the Node.js api. It would be wonderful if someone already implemented it with boost::asio or similar.

Comment: Added additional thought to my answer - I've not looked at the library, just at the description of it but it might help?

Comment: libuv is still under active development and it's probably unwise to use it in production

Comment: true, now I look closer it It doesn't seem to be exactly what the original poster is looking for anyway, more something that could help with implmenting what he wants.

Comment: Even it was stable libuv is still a low level library with no event subscriptions and etc. Looking at echo_server.c example it is huge - not the mere 5 lines echoserver in node.js

Comment: @Roskoto as mentioned `boost::asio` will do what you want, it's just huge and would require learning. node.js considered using `boost::asio` and mentioned "it just works" but it didn't want to because well it's huge.

Comment: asio is really good, I use it for a fairly major project. And it's not that hard to learn.  It's more that if you want http and database connections on top of it, you'll have to programm that yourself.

Answer (score 2):

[Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/rationale.html) is conceptually very similar to Node.js. The primary difference being Asio is implemented as a library and Node.js is a language construct. Asio therefore exposes the event queue, requiring some initial setup to post callback handlers, and eventually a blocking call to start the event loop (`io_service.run()`).

If you're looking for a pure C++ API similar to Node.js, Boost.Asio is definitely the way to go. It is the de-facto networking library for many C++ applications. It's also discussed heavily on SO in the [boost-asio](/questions/tagged/boost-asio) tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you could embed a Javascript engine into your program

- v8 ([building guide](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/build.html))
- SpiderMonkey ([building guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SpiderMonkey/Build_Documentation))

Actually tying that to your C code needs tinkering with the eval functions of both, but I think I remember seeing sample programs doing that for both engines

Comment: I'm quite sure my boss would not agree with you :) Our server should be strictly C/C++.

Comment: Meh. It answered _your_ question, though :) Perhaps you could update it

Comment: To the downvoter: _I_ have personally had to edit the question to show the 'c++ only' part. It may be obvious to _you_ now, but it is a bit useless to downvote a proper answer. Just don't upvote it :)